# Java: Regex expression to match FTP response codes

Tags: java, regex, ftp

I'm creating an FTP client in JAVA without using any FTP libraries and I want to know when the FTP response is finished by using a regular expression so I know when to stop reading. So I'm trying to create a regular expression that looks for any three digits and a space afterward so I can tell my program to stop reading lines from the connection.

Here's what I currently have: `response.matches("^[0-9][0-9][0-9](?:\\s)")`

It should catch codes like: `"230 Process complete"`, or `"543 Have a nice day!"`, but not a response like `"400- There's more to be read..."`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you're using `matches(...)`, the regex **must** match the entire line (which also makes the `^` redundant). Either use `matches("[0-9]{3}\\s.*")` or use the `find()` method on `Matcher`.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```java
String response = "543 Have a nice day!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3}) ([\\w !]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("code: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("message: " + matcher.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("the code is not recognized");
}
```

Output:

```
code: 543
message: Have a nice day!
```